# Make MariaDB run on boot without networking

Tags: linux, systemd, mariadb

I am running a timer python program I made on a raspberry pi with raspbian. The idea is for the timer to start when the pi boots (systemd) and stop when the pi is unplugged. It saves to a MariaDB database at constant intervals so that when it is unplugged its state will be saved. My problem is that MariaDB is a dependency, and MariaDB doesn't start until after networking. Since dhcp takes time to start, my program doesn't get started until networking and MariaDB are started, and that takes >10 sec.

Is there a way to run MariaDB without networking on only localhost and start it before dhcp is finished?

Comment: I don't know raspberry pi well. But, if it is a systemd-based distribution, then duplicate /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service in /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service , with your changes (removed network dependency).

Comment: I had tried removing the network dependency, but I hadn't noticed a significant difference. I just timed it, and there is actually about 5 sec cut off. I guess that answered my question.

Comment: There are tools to analyze the systemd log (journal), what it did, when, and why. Anyways, it is a super*user* site, and you are clearly a developer. I would suggest to try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Btw, in an embedded environment I would prefer sqlite to mysql. In a not embedded environment, I would prefer postgresql to mysql. In any environment I would prefer anything to mysql. But it is only my personal opinion, you can have yours and I honor it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if mariadb will run without the network but peterh's solution is basically the right way to go. On my testserver there is also a "syslog.target" in the "After=" part. Maybe you want to try removing that as well if you don't depend on logging during mariadb startup. But I don't really know how soon syslog starts so this might not speed up things significantly.

In any case you need to tell systemd about your changes by doing a reload like so

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Otherwise systemd will not change the startup sequence and your changes will be ignored (unless you reboot the entire system, that works as well).

Furthermore please be aware that when overriding the entire systemd service file like you tried you will be stuck with your version of that file. That means if mariadb updates the original /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service your file will not be updated and you might miss important changes.